# Setting up UDP with Julia

Tags: udp, julia

How to setup UDP communication interface in a LAN using Julia? I seem to recognize Base/socket.jl in the Julia repo but there is hardly any documentation on how to use the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, documentation on UDP is still missing now, but maybe we can learn how to use UDP via [the TCP example](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/networking-and-streams/?highlight=tcp#a-simple-tcp-example). Here is my testing code.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.4.0-dev+6494"

julia> @async begin
         udpsock = UDPSocket()
         bind(udpsock,ip"127.0.0.1",2000)
         while true
           println(bytestring(recv(udpsock)))
         end
       end
Task (waiting) @0x000000010c2a1900

julia> sock = UDPSocket()
UDPSocket(Ptr{Void} @0x00007f91e430d530,1,Condition(Any[]),Condition(Any[]),Condition(Any[]))

julia> send(sock,ip"127.0.0.1",2000,"Hello World from the UDP")
Hello World from the UDP
```

note that, if you are using julia v0.3.*, you should use `UdpSocket()` instead of `UDPSocket()`.

UPDATE: I forgot to initialize(use `bind()`) the socket, which results in `close(sock)` throwing an error.

```
julia> sock = UDPSocket()
UDPSocket(Ptr{Void} @0x00007f91e430d530,1,Condition(Any[]),Condition(Any[]),Condition(Any[]))

julia> bind(sock,ip"127.0.0.1",1000)
true

julia> send(sock,ip"127.0.0.1",2000,"Hello World from the UDP")
Hello World from the UDP

julia> close(sock)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I seem to get this error that UDPSocket() is not defined. I am on v 0.3.8. Does it matter?

Comment: no, just change `UDPSocket()` to `UdpSocket()`. [reference here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v0.3.8/base/socket.jl)

Comment: I have been trying a few things with UdpSocket() in Julia. I could never close a socket I create. @gnimuc Eg. Python has a simple close(sock) command