# How to establish a client - server architecture using UDP in Julia?

Tags: udp, julia

I am trying to send packets between two computers over LAN. I have got little help from Julia documentation. For example: How to do something like this http://pymotw.com/2/socket/udp.html

Comment: "I have got little help from Julia documentation."

Really? 

http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/networking-and-streams/?highlight=port#a-simple-tcp-example

Comment: I didn't see the UDP part, I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843319/setting-up-udp-with-julia You could add that example to the Julia manual documentation: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/doc/manual/networking-and-streams.rst

Comment: Also see: Added recvfrom to get source address of UDP packets (#9418). https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9418